# make thunderbird behave more like gmail

Tags: macos, thunderbird, gmail

Right now I'm using Sparrow, because of how well it works with gmail in a gmail-like fashion. However, I'm now forced to use Thunderbird because of a couple of extensions, and I'd like it to integrate better with gmail.

What I'm looking for is mostly a similar behavior for **archive** and that the folder tree is respected (sent messages go inside [gmail]/[sent mail], etc...)
Also: similar conversation view.

Any ideas? What do you guys know of?

Thanks

Comment: If you want Gmail, use Gmail's web interface or Sparrow. Thunderbird is an all-purpose email client that tries to conform to standards, something that Gmail is not. E.g. Gmail's IMAP "implementation".

Comment: I edited the question to detail some more what I'm looking for. Thanks @slhck

Comment: @lupincho not a very useful comment ^^

Comment: my comment may be harsh (sorry for that), but it is actually very useful as it is based on a lot of experience. Think of this as a suggestion for you not to try to match things that are not entirely compatible. Because of Gmail's non-compliance to standards it is hard to make a (somehow) standard-compliant email client (TB, even Outlook) confront to non-standards. Just doesn't happen. Clients that are designed to work with fine Gmail do that, work fine with Gmail. But none of the all-purpose clients works Gmail-like, they work "kind of" with Gmail. If Sparrow works for you, use that.

Comment: No problem, it's not that your comment is harsh, I actually agree with you and if I could I would keep using Sparrow, which works fantastically for me. However, I want to use some extensions that are only available for Thunderbird, so I don't have that option.